# Changing img using an event onclick function using javascript -- resolved

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a hard time understanding why my page won't change every time I click on a specific attribute.

I have my html of where my first image is located:

```
<!-- Face Column Starts -->
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="float-right" id="face">
          <!-- Image size: 587 width x 419 height -->
          <img src="../static/images/face.png" alt="" width="350" usemap="#facemap" href="#face" class="face" onlick="changeProduct()">
          <map name="facemap">
            <div class="blush">
              <area  shape="circle" coords="260,185,25" href="#blush" alt="blush" onclick="changeProduct()">
              <area shape="circle" coords="100,185,25" href="#blush" alt="blush" onclick="changeProduct()">
            </div>
            <div class="eyeshadow">
              <area  alt="eyeshadow" id="right" href="#eyeshadow" shape="poly" coords="222,116,230,102,245,90,265,83,286,84,318,100,312,109,290,98,259,100,222,116 " onclick="changeProduct()">
              <area alt="eyeshadow" id="left" href="#eyeshadow" shape="poly" coords="133,116,113,106,78,97,45,105,38,104,65,80,89,80,90,81,97,83,105,86,133,116" onclick="changeProduct()">
            </div>
            <div class="eyeliner">
              <area  alt="eyeliner" id="right" href="#eyeliner" shape="poly" coords="220,118,259,100,275,100,295,100,305,105,315,110,300,115,275,122,259,124,222,118 " onclick="changeProduct()">
              <area alt="eyeliner" id="left" href="#eyeliner" shape="poly" coords="131,118,113,106,78,97,42,107,65,120,89,126,105,124,133,118" onclick="changeProduct()">
            </div>
            <area class="foundation" shape="rect" coords="0,419,587,0" href="#foundation" alt="foundation" onclick="changeProduct()">
          </map>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Face Column Ends -->
```

I used a map so that I can click on different regions of the face. When I do that, I'd like it to alternate between a different picture.

This is what I used in my javascript file:

```
    var image =  document.getElementById("face");

    function changeProduct() {
        if (image.getAttribute('alt') == "blush") {
            image.src = "../images/blush.png";
        } else if (image.getAttribute('alt') === "foundation") {
            image.src = "../images/foundation.png";
        } else if (image.getAttribute('alt') === "eyeshadow") {
            image.src = "../images/eyeshadow.png";
        } else {
            image.src = "../images/eyeliner.png";
        }
    }
```

Expected output: When I click on the blush (cheeks) my image goes from [face](https://github.com/nawdah/project-2/blob/master/static/images/face.png)! to [blush](https://github.com/nawdah/project-2/blob/master/static/images/blush.png)!

However, I see no change.

Can someone please help clarify what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE: I tried a different method and got the correct result from what I wanted, I created 4 different variables for each instance and added an event listener click function rather than the HTML onclick. for anyone who may have a similar problem in the future, here is how I solved my error:

```
var foundationListen = document.querySelectorAll("[alt='foundation']");

for(var i=0; i < foundationListen.length; i++){

    foundationListen[i].addEventListener("click", function(){

        var image =  document.querySelector("div#face img");
        image.src = "../static/images/foundation.png";

    });

};
```

Thank you to those in the comments that helped!!

Comment: Will it be possible for you to create a working demo of the issue  you are facing. You can use dummy images from  the web.. Will be easy to help..

Comment: the ALT attribute of the image (your variable image points to) never changes .. why not simply pass the "aspect" value inside the onclick? onclick="changeProduct('eyeliner')"

Comment: you assigned the face id to the div no to the img tag i think !! try to change it think it will solve your problem !!!

Comment: I think the way you tried to implement is all wrong, can you add your expected output

Comment: I added my output in the update at the end of the code! @AkhilAravind

Comment: @NadaIbrahim do you need to change image on clicking the part of image ??. thats what you tried to do now. Or you need to add an image on some part of the dom. can you please share your expected output image. ( not the error, your actual expected output )

Comment: That's not how [`<map>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) is used,.

Comment: @AkhilAravind I posted what my expectations for the image change should be as I don't have the html file running outside of my folder yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the onclick method didn't work for me so I attached click listeners to each attribute I wanted to click on and just changed the image source. here is the code that worked for me!

```
var foundationListen = document.querySelectorAll("[alt='foundation']");

for(var i=0; i < foundationListen.length; i++){

    foundationListen[i].addEventListener("click", function(){

        var image =  document.querySelector("div#face img");
        image.src = "../static/images/foundation.png";

    });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the div `src` instead of the image

Change this line

```
var image =  document.getElementById("face");
```

to select the image element instead as such

```
var image =  document.querySelector("div#face img");
```

**Note:** You might need to change the function to have argument instead as @flowtron said, something like

```
function changeProduct(alt) {
    if(!alt) return;
    image.src = `../image/${alt}.png`;
}
```

And use it as below

```html
<area  shape="circle" coords="260,185,25" href="#blush" alt="blush" onclick="changeProduct('blush')">
<area shape="circle" coords="100,185,25" href="#blush" alt="blush" onclick="changeProduct('blush')">
<!-- And so on. You get the idea -->
```

If you use your above function however, you need to call `changeProduct(this)` and the element in if check needs to be the area element (this) alt attribute

```
function changeProduct(areaElem){
    const alt = areaElem.getAttribute('alt');
    if(alt === 'blush'){
        image.src = ...
    }
    // And so on
}
```

Comment: This no longer gives me an error but it won't change the image on the click

Comment: @NadaIbrahim If you use your code above for the function, `image` element in the if check should be another element like `document.querySelector(\`.${alt} area\`)`

Comment: Can you clarify a little more? I'm relatively new to JS

Comment: I suggest you add an answer which explains what went wrong and how you fix it

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is `img` not `div`.

Please replace the line - `var image =  document.getElementById("face");`

with this one - `var image =  document.getElementById("face").getElementsByTagName('img')[0];`

See the working example below

```js
    function changeProduct() {
        var image =  document.getElementById("face").getElementsByTagName('img').length > 0 ? document.getElementById("face").getElementsByTagName('img')[0] : document.getElementById("face").getElementsByTagName('area')[0];
        if (image.getAttribute('alt') == "blush") {
            image.src = "../image/blush.png";
        } else if (image.getAttribute('alt') === "foundation") {
            image.src = "../image/foundation.png";
        } else if (image.getAttribute('alt') === "eyeshadow") {
            image.src = "../image/eyeshadow.png";
        } else {
            image.src = "../image/eyeliner.png";
        }
    }
```

```html
<!-- Face Column Starts -->
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="float-right" id="face">
          <!-- Image size: 587 width x 419 height -->
          <img src="../static/images/face.png" alt="img" width="350" usemap="#facemap" href="#face" class="face" onlick="changeProduct()">
          <map name="facemap">
            <div class="blush">
              <area  shape="circle" coords="260,185,25" href="#blush" alt="blush" onclick="changeProduct()">
              <area shape="circle" coords="100,185,25" href="#blush" alt="blush" onclick="changeProduct()">
            </div>
            <div class="eyeshadow">
              <area  alt="eyeshadow" id="right" href="#eyeshadow" shape="poly" coords="222,116,230,102,245,90,265,83,286,84,318,100,312,109,290,98,259,100,222,116 " onclick="changeProduct()">
              <area alt="eyeshadow" id="left" href="#eyeshadow" shape="poly" coords="133,116,113,106,78,97,45,105,38,104,65,80,89,80,90,81,97,83,105,86,133,116" onclick="changeProduct()">
            </div>
            <div class="eyeliner">
              <area  alt="eyeliner" id="right" href="#eyeliner" shape="poly" coords="220,118,259,100,275,100,295,100,305,105,315,110,300,115,275,122,259,124,222,118 " onclick="changeProduct()">
              <area alt="eyeliner" id="left" href="#eyeliner" shape="poly" coords="131,118,113,106,78,97,42,107,65,120,89,126,105,124,133,118" onclick="changeProduct()">
            </div>
            <area class="foundation" shape="rect" coords="0,419,587,0" href="#foundation" alt="foundation" onclick="changeProduct()">
          </map>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Face Column Ends -->
```

Comment: This gives me a type error in the console, getElementsByTag is null

Comment: @NadaIbrahim, But it is working here in snippet. Have you changed your Html code?

Comment: No i didnt @Alok Mali

Comment: @NadaIbrahim, the code is fine. I am surprised, why it is not working on your end.

Comment: My exact error is Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null, I have done nothing different to the html

Comment: It will have lots of changes. I will update it after some time.

Comment: @NadaIbrahim, That's really great.